# Performance implications for event buses

Tags: vue.js

In our Vue app, we use multiple event buses to receive/send events.

**Method A: Separate event buses**

Some components only need to deal with one channel (we just import the buses we need).

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const CanvasBus = new Vue()
export const NotificationBus = new Vue()
export const FileBus = new Vue()
export const UIBus = new Vue()
```

**Method B: One event bus**

We could have just one event bus which deals with all events, but it means all events are sent to all listeners.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

With this method, each event would have an extra parameter being `type` (which would be "Canvas", "UI", "File", etc.).

**Question:**
Are there performance implications one way or another, such as having to load multiple Vue instances, or there's no worry and it just comes down to organizational preference?

Comment: how are you listening to events?   if its via $on   then it's unlikely to cost you anything.  I haven't checked the implementation, but I'd imagine it would be a hashed look up and then dispatch to subscribers

Comment: Yes we use $on's (like: `CanvasBus.$on("someAction", (payload) => { console.log(payload) })`). We manually set them up in components, based on needs. Then inside a given $on, we may use switch/case logic if there's many actions to define (e.g. one bus has ~50 events we're listening for).